# append line command not working in terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am trying to append CDPATH automatically in the `~/.bash_profile` and I am doing it by using the command

```
ex -sc 's/$/:/opt/|w|q' ~/.bash_profile
```

When I run this, the terminal hangs whereas the below command works just fine

```
ex -sc 's/$/yourText2/|w|q' ~/.bash_profile
```

What is wrong in the first command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the unescaped `/` in your replacement text `:/opt`

You must either escape it

```
ex -sc 's/$/:\/opt/|w|q' file
```

or use an alternate separator for the `s` command

```
ex -sc 's@$@:/opt@|w|q' file
```